# Sql to get number of hours per user per day

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-redshift

A table '**Log**' has the below columns:

```
SystemName
User
Datetime - it's a timestamp
Status - has the values Start or Stop.
```

I need to write a query which will give me :
Number of hours spent per user per day on system X.

Please see example data below:

```
X, Amit, 05/01/2019 08:45:00, Start
X, Amit, 05/03/2019 13:25:00, Stop
X, Dave, 05/01/2019 09:10:35, Start
X, Dave, 05/01/2019 17:35:42, Stop
```

Output:

```
Amit,05/01/2019, 15h
Amit,05/02/2019, 24h
Amit,05/03/2019, 9h
Dave,05/01/2019, 8h
```

My approach till now :
I was thinking I could use lead or lag to get the consecutive times in the same row. But in the case of user Amit that spans across multiple days. Also there could be a user who has started and stopped multiple times on the same day. Even if I do that how could I generate hours for the dates amidst the range. Can you please help me.

Comment: Idea is to enumerate all hours within the range (this is DBMS specific), ang group by date.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. You will only get Hours spent if both Start and Stop status exists for a user in a single day.

```
SELECT SystemName,[user],
CONVERT(varchar, CAST(Datetime AS DATETIME), 1) Datetime,
DATEDIFF
(
    HH,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Ststus = 'Start' THEN [Datetime] ELSE NULL END ),
    MAX(CASE WHEN Ststus = 'Stop' THEN Datetime ELSE NULL END )
)HourSpent
FROM your_table A
GROUP BY SystemName,[User],
CONVERT(varchar, CAST(Datetime AS DATETIME), 1)
```

Comment: In the example of Amit, the start and stop is across 2 days. How do we generate the hours for 05/02/2019 ? Would you be able to share a sqlfiddle link to the solution you proposed here?

Comment: @AnilKulkarni I mentioned in the details that this solution will only work if there Start and Stop available for a same day. In the sample output, the OP also shown day wise spent time and I prepared the script accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Since the output consists of one row per User + Day, then you would need to JOIN the data to a calendar table of dates.

You would need a way to extract the Start and Stop timestamp pairs for a given user, join it to the calendar table, then count the number of hours on that day that are between the start and stop times. (The hour count could be use a [User Defined Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/user-defined-functions.html).

That's pretty complex. Frankly, I would rather **write a Python program to parse the data rather than doing it via SQL**. It would be very simple:

- Read start line
- Read end line
- Loop through days, outputting hours per day (quite simple in Python)

Sometimes the best hammer is a spanner. (Translation: Sometimes a different tool is better.)